# How to maintain history snapshot in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a huge object collection in mongoDB. These are basically products from a shopping website fetched from their APIs. Stored like:

```
{
    "id": "some_id"
    "baseInfo": {
        "identifiers": {
            "attributes": {
                "description": "some desc"
                "title": "some title"
                "price": {
                    "amount": "amount"
                    "currency": "currency"
                }
                "....": "..."
                ... snip ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This info keeps on changing and is updated by a python script hitting their API continuously.

What would be the easiest way to maintain what changes occurred to which object at what time. For example:
in Nth run of the script, at time T1 the product with ID=I, changed it's price from P1 to P2. Similarly, N+1th run at time T2 the price was changed to P3. So basically what would be the easiest way to store the pricing history of the product with ID=I?

Comment: Please see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30306918/299871

Answer (score 0):

I would alter the python script to track the changes in a new collection. Use `findAndModify` to update the each product and retrieve the old version atomically, then push the old version into another collection of historical info, appending on a valid date (or date range) and possibly a version number. You could alternatively have the new collection store changes by computing the changes between old and new versions and storing that in the collection.